# What exactly is temporary worker?

Tags: word-usage

I can't find a definition for this word, but aren't all workers technically temporary? Do English speakers use this word often or another word that has a similar definition?

Comment: No, all workers are not temporary. A temporary one would be employed on the understanding that it was only for a short period.

Comment: It is a common phrase among English speakers in the USA, well, common when you're discussing employees and hiring decisions. It's a convention. Yes, all employees are temporary -- nobody works forever, but people don't like to be reminded of that, I suppose. :)

Comment: In the UK a 'permanent' job is one where you can probably stay until you reach retirement age, and a temporary job is one where you know the date you will finish (for example three months after starting). Of course nothing is truly permanent (we don't live for ever), and you can lose a 'permanent' job if you are fired for a legal reason, or the company fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see this word in the dictionary here it is.

https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=temporary

Unfortunately, it is not a term that is registered in the dictionary. However, it did come up in this translation from Spanish, with a definition in English (look below to see the alternatives.

- Employment on short-term contract
- Temporary job
- Temp job
- Temporary employee

Are all used to refer to these. It specifically means, that a person who is only hired to do a job for a shorter than normal period of time. For example, when someone is ill and have to take a couple of weeks off work, the person who takes their place would be a temporary employee.

Comment: Often, a "temporary worker" (or a "temp", colloquially) is not even an employee of the company that needs the work done.  They work for a "temp agency" that hires them out to the company that needs the "temp work" to be done.